# How can I remove archive button from tree view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I do not want my user group to archive records when my user group has the create and write rights. For kanban view "archivable='false'" is an option but for the list view, this does not exist. How can I remove or don't show this button for that user group?

Answer (score 2):

Add `groups='your_module.your_group'` to your active field.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically hide for the specific user with **fields_view_get** method.

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, 
    submenu=False):
res = super(Classname, self).fields_view_get(
    view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
if view_type == 'tree' and self.user_has_groups('Your Group') and Other Condition:
    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
    for node in doc.xpath("//your button"):
        node.set('modifiers', json.dumps({'invisible': 1}))
    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc, encoding='unicode')
return res
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **group** option in button menu like this

`<button name="order_confirm" states="draft" string="Confirm Order" groups="xml id( group)"/>`

This will show that particular button for specific group only..